# having troubles with handling large data in R

Tags: r

Im currently making recommender system with 8k users and 200k items using recommenderlab package.

Before using the functions of recommenderlab, I'm having troubles with converting my data frame to real rating matrix.

```
    item_idx                    mem_idx         rating
1   00600015987465341234f7dae4  534122168382b   4
2   0060001660924533ad0cd443e1  53d79f413e3aa   5
3   006000195520453d7ac28e4b4b  53d79f413e3aa   5
4   0060001986642536d6fc77d269  535146eb5af95   4
5   00708969975005409278f828f3  540927366f478   5
```

This is the part of my data frame, all the (item_idx, mem_idx) pairs are distinct.

```
mat <- tapply(df$rating, list(df$mem_idx, df$ID), FUN=function(x) x)
```

I tried to convert data frame to matrix using this code, some times success but usually there occur error like this.

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 Gb
```

In the succeeded case,

```
r <- as(mat, "realRatingMatrix")
```

I applied this code to make it realRatingMatrix
But I always failed with this error

```
Error in which(x == 0, arr.ind = TRUE) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which': Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Anyone who knows how to escape one of these errors, please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the dataframe to a sparse matrix and then to realRatingMatrix class

```
itm <- factor(data[,1])
mem <- factor(data[,2])

# sparsematrix
s <- sparseMatrix(
    as.numeric(itm), 
    as.numeric(mem),
    dimnames = list(
            as.character(levels(itm)), 
            as.character(levels(mem))),
    x = data[,3])

#convert to realRatingMatrix class
rm <- new("realRatingMatrix",data=s)
```